# How to filter out a value from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

How to remove the value "nissan", from an array of objects?

```
const cars = [
   {type: "audi", amount: 2},
   {type: "nissan", amount: 12},
   {type: "mazda", amount: 5},
   {type: "volvo", amount: 5}
]
```

This is how I display all the types and amounts:

```
cars.map(car => {
   return (
     <div>{car.type}: {car.amount}</div>
   );
});
```

But I would like to remove the value "nissan", before mapping over the cars, how could I do that with .filter?

```
removeNissan() {
   // cars.type !== "nissan"
}

cars.filter(removeNissan).map(car => {
   return (
     <div>{car.type}: {car.amount}</div>
   );
});
```

Comment: `filter(car => car.type !== 'nissan')`…

Comment: What have you tried? `removeNissan` is going to be passed some parameters by `.filter`. Have you looked into what gets passed to this, either in experiment or through research?

Comment: As per given code, you are using `Array.filter`. You have also written the condition but is commented. Can you please elaborate, what is the issue with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function before `map` function

```
const cars = [
   {type: "audi", amount: 2},
   {type: "nissan", amount: 12},
   {type: "mazda", amount: 5},
   {type: "volvo", amount: 5}
]


cars.filter(item => item.type !== 'nissan').map(car => {
   return (
     <div>{car.type}: {car.amount}</div>
   );
});
```

Or if you want to use a named function, declare your function

```
removeNissan(car) {
   return car.type !== "nissan";
}
```

filter will pass the each item as argument to the function.